# How to show two list items result into one, for multiple results. Using java in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Here need to print two list results in the particular format by combining two list data. For example: as show in image 
Normal(5-7Days): Rs. 2,400.00  
Fast(3-5Days): Rs. 3,000.00
Express(2-3Days): Rs. 3,600.00

[image]

Here is my code

```
 List<WebElement> ShippingLabel = driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //label[contains(@class,'radio__label')]")); 
 List<WebElement> ShippingPrice = driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //label[contains(@class,'radio__label')]/following-sibling::span")); 

 for (WebElement SLelement: ShippingLabel) {
       System.out.println("Testingl:"+SLelement.getText());
 }
 for (WebElement SPelement1: ShippingPrice) {
     System.out.println("Testinglp:"+SPelement1.getText());
    }
```

Comment: what does your code print?

Comment: Below is my Result those i get on console: 

Testingl:Normal(5-7Days)
Testingl:Fast(3-5Days) , 
Testingl:Express(2-3Days) , 
Testinglp:Rs. 2,400.00 , 
Testinglp:Rs. 3,000.00 ,
Testinglp:Rs. 3,600.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not this:

```
List<WebElement> ShippingLabel = driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //label[contains(@class,'radio__label')]")); 
 List<WebElement> ShippingPrice = driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //label[contains(@class,'radio__label')]/following-sibling::span")); 

 for (int i = 0; i < ShippingLabel.size(); i++) {
     WebElement ele1 = ShippingLabel.get(i);
     WebElement ele2 = ShippingPrice.get(i);

     System.out.println(ele1.getText() + ":" + ele2.getText());
 }
```